# Why does my QML application not look normal in iPad simulator?

Tags: ios, qt, ipad, qml, qt-creator

I have difficulties with MVC architecture in my QML application.

I tested it on my **iPad**, and it looks well:

[image: Screenshot from iPad]

But when I tried to run this in the **iPad simulator** via Qt Creator, it looks terrible:

[image: Screenshot from simulator]

Qt: 5.4, using framework7

Why is it like this?

Comment: Any QML errors on the console?

Comment: No, qml console doesn't have errors.